# How do I use two different querySelectors in an if statement to display two different messages

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement, css-selectors

I have two `div` elements with the `ids` `displayText` and `refreshText`. They have almost the same CSS styling, apart from trying to position `refreshText` below `displayText`. In the JavaScript, I used two `querySelectors` to try to accomplish this within an `if` statement. However, it doesn't seem to work. Can I use two separate `querySelectors` within the same `if-else` statement?

```js
//DETERMINE WINNER FUNCTION
function determineWinner({
  player,
  enemy,
  timerId
}) {
  clearTimeout(timerId)
  document.querySelector('#displayText').style.display = 'flex'
  if (player.health === enemy.health) {
    document.querySelector('#displayText').innerHTML = 'Tie'
    document.querySelector('#refreshText').innerHTML = 'Refresh Screen to Continue'
  } else if (player.health > enemy.health) {
    document.querySelector('#displayText').innerHTML = 'Player 1 Wins'
    document.querySelector('#refreshText').innerHTML = 'Refresh Screen to Continue'
  } else if (enemy.health > player.health) {
    document.querySelector('#displayText').innerHTML = 'Player 2 Wins'
    document.querySelector('#refreshText').innerHTML = 'Refresh Screen to Continue'
  }
}
```

```css
#displayText {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  display: none;
}

#refreshText {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 10;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="red-container">
  <!--Smaller container-->
  <div id="smaller-red-container">

    <!-- player health -->
    <div id="player-container">
      <div id="player-health"></div>
      <div id="player-health-cover"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- timer -->
    <div id="timer">
      10
    </div>

    <!-- enemy health -->
    <div id="enemy-container">
      <div id="enemy-health"></div>
      <div id="enemy-health-cover"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="displayText">Tie</div>
  <div id="refreshText">Refresh Screen</div>
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.10.4/gsap.min.js" integrity="sha512-VEBjfxWUOyzl0bAwh4gdLEaQyDYPvLrZql3pw1ifgb6fhEvZl9iDDehwHZ+dsMzA0Jfww8Xt7COSZuJ/slxc4Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">
</script>
```

Comment: The problem must be somewhere else, because this code is fine

Comment: What specifically "doesn't seem to work"?  When you step through the code in a debugger, which specific operation doesn't do what you expect?  What were the runtime values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: Specifically the second querySelector doesn't display it's message at all but the first one does. I have both set to display none in CSS so they only display when the conditions are met in JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a `Player` class and then created two players, `tom` and `jerry`. You can set their health to see how the results are displayed.

I changed the way that `determineWinner()` accepts arguments, so that it accepts three arguments and not an object.

The problem must be with the way you are calling your function or with the CSS, so I created a `checkWinner()` function and called your function `determineWinner()` from there.

I removed the initial `innerText` of the two message `divs`, and I changed the color of the messages from `red` to `white`.

Your `if else` code seems to work.

```js
//DETERMINE WINNER FUNCTION
function determineWinner(
  player,
  enemy,
  timerId
) {
  clearTimeout(timerId)
  document.querySelector('#displayText').style.display = 'flex'
  if (player.health === enemy.health) {
    document.querySelector('#displayText').innerText = 'Tie'
    document.querySelector('#refreshText').innerText = 'Refresh Screen to Continue'
  } else if (player.health > enemy.health) {
    document.querySelector('#displayText').innerText = 'Player 1 Wins'
    document.querySelector('#refreshText').innerText = 'Refresh Screen to Continue'
  } else if (enemy.health > player.health) {
    document.querySelector('#displayText').innerText = 'Player 2 Wins'
    document.querySelector('#refreshText').innerText = 'Refresh Screen to Continue'
  }
}

class Player {
  constructor(health) {
    this.health = Number(health);
  }
}

function checkWinner() {
  let tom = new Player(document.querySelector('#tomHealth').value);
  let jerry = new Player(document.querySelector('#jerryHealth').value);

  determineWinner(jerry, tom, null);
}
```

```css
#displayText {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 20;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
}

#refreshText {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 10;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Player 1 (jerry)<input type="number" id="jerryHealth" value="6"> Player 2 (tom)<input type="number" id="tomHealth" value="5">
  <button onclick="checkWinner()">Check Winner</button>
</div>
<div id="red-container">
  <!--Smaller container-->
  <div id="smaller-red-container">

    <!-- player health -->
    <div id="player-container">
      <div id="player-health"></div>
      <div id="player-health-cover"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- timer -->
    <div id="timer">
      10
    </div>

    <!-- enemy health -->
    <div id="enemy-container">
      <div id="enemy-health"></div>
      <div id="enemy-health-cover"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="displayText"></div>
  <div id="refreshText"></div>
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I still can't find the issue but this helps!